# How to merge two dataframes when a column of one of the dataframes contains sub-string of a column in the other dataframe in a time efficient manner

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: one having the product review string and the other having the review message string which is a sub-string of the product review string as shown below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ProductReview':['11/02/2020 c1r1 good product','27/08/2020 c2r1 product function1 could be better', '01/02/2020 c3r1 satisfactory product'], 'Feature1': ['feature21','feature22','feature23'], 'Feature2': ['feature11','feature12','feature13']})

    ProductReview                                       Feature1    Feature2
0   11/02/2020 c1r1 good product                        feature21   feature11
1   27/08/2020 c2r1 product function1 could be better   feature22   feature12
2   01/02/2020 c3r1 satisfactory product                feature23   feature13



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['c1r1','c2r1'], 'ReviewMessage' : ['good product','product function1 could be better'],'New_value':['1','2']})

  Column1   ReviewMessage                     New_value
0   c1r1    good product                        1
1   c2r1    product function1 could be better   2
```

Not all the rows in df1 have a row in df2.

I'm trying to merge these two dataframes by making use of the fact that `ReviewMessage` column is a sub string of `ProductReview` column. I tried doing this using for loops to see if each ReviewMessage is a substring of the ProductReview but it's taking too much time.

Is there any time-efficient pythonic way of doing this. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit 1**: Note that the occurrence of r1 in that particular position is not always the case in the original dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the product name with a regex (the real one might change on your real case dataset) and merge on it:

```
df1['Column1'] = df1['ProductReview'].str.extract('^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\s+([^\s]+)')
df1.merge(df2, on='Column1', how='left')
```

output:

```
                                       ProductReview   Feature1   Feature2 Column1                      ReviewMessage New_value
0                       11/02/2020 c1r1 good product  feature21  feature11    c1r1                       good product         1
1  27/08/2020 c2r1 product function1 could be better  feature22  feature12    c2r1  product function1 could be better         2
2               01/02/2020 c3r1 satisfactory product  feature23  feature13    c3r1                                NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the ProductReview column on `r1` (assuming that this is always the case), and use `pd.merge` to join on the substring, as below:

```
df1['t'] = df1['ProductReview'].str.split('r1').str[-1].str.strip()
merged = df1.merge(df2,how='left',left_on='t',right_on='ReviewMessage').drop('t',axis=1)
```

Prints back:

```
                                       ProductReview   Feature1   Feature2 Column1                      ReviewMessage New_value
0                       11/02/2020 c1r1 good product  feature21  feature11    c1r1                       good product         1
1  27/08/2020 c2r1 product function1 could be better  feature22  feature12    c2r1  product function1 could be better         2
2               01/02/2020 c3r1 satisfactory product  feature23  feature13     NaN                                NaN       NaN
```

Comment: c1r1 kind of token is just a place-holder token, I gave a small example of. It is not always the case that we find r1 at that particular position. But still, thanks for your efforts.